# How to refresh a grid from a redirected page

Tags: acumatica

I have an inquiry page where the Header is the POLine table and the grid is a new table linked to POLine. I cannot use an unbounded DAC for the filters because I want to offer the option to navigate over existing records.

If I open the page directly and enter the POLine information, the grid is refreshed correctly.

I included a button in the Purchase Orders page with an action that opens my inquiry page. In this scenario, the filter is loaded correctly but the grid does not show the records until the grid's refresh button is pressed.

This is my Action:

```
public PXAction<POOrder> Reconcile;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reconcile", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true, OnClosingPopup = PXSpecialButtonType.Cancel)]
    public virtual void reconcile()
        {
            POLine pOLineRow = Transactions.Current;

            if (pOLineRow == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (pOLineRow.OrderNbr != null)
            {
                PEPOOrderReconciliationMaint pEPOOrderReconciliationgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PEPOOrderReconciliationMaint>();

                pEPOOrderReconciliationgraph.POOrderReconcileRecord.Current = pEPOOrderReconciliationgraph.POOrderReconcileRecord.Search<POLine.orderType, POLine.orderNbr, POLine.lineNbr>(pOLineRow.OrderType, pOLineRow.OrderNbr, pOLineRow.LineNbr, pOLineRow.OrderType);


                if (pEPOOrderReconciliationgraph.POOrderReconcileRecord.Current != null)
                {    
                    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(pEPOOrderReconciliationgraph, false, "PORECONCILIATION") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
                }
            }
        }
```

I have not used the Search<> method at a detail level before, but I found this Acumatica reference in POReceiptEntry:

```
    POLineR polineR = _graph.purchaseLinesUPD.Search<POLineR.orderType, POLineR.orderNbr, POLineR.lineNbr>
(itemsource.OrderType, itemsource.OrderNbr, itemsource.LineNbr);
```

I also tried to assign the value directly with a PXSelect:

```
    pEPOOrderReconciliationgraph.POOrderReconcileRecord.Current = PXSelect<POLine,Where<POLine.orderType, 
Equal<Required<POLine.orderType>>,And<POLine.orderNbr, 
Equal<Required<POLine.orderNbr>>,And<POLine.lineNbr, 
Equal<Required<POLine.lineNbr>>>>>>
.Select(this, pOLineRow.OrderType, pOLineRow.OrderNbr, pOLineRow.LineNbr);
```

I don't think this is related to the error though. I think it's more oriented to a refresh option in the ASPX.

This is my ASPX code:

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FormDetail.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="PR501000.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_PR501000" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/FormDetail.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%" TypeName="Purchase.PEPOOrderReconciliationMaint" PrimaryView="POOrderReconcileRecord">
        <CallbackCommands>
            <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="SaveClose" Visible="false" PopupVisible="false"/>
            <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="Save" Visible="false" CommitChanges="true"/>
            <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="Cancel" Visible="true" CommitChanges="true"/>
            <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="Insert" Visible="false" CommitChanges="true"/>
            <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="CopyPaste" Visible="false" CommitChanges="true"/>
            <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="Delete" Visible="false" CommitChanges="true"/>
        </CallbackCommands>
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100" 
        Width="100%" DataMember="POOrderReconcileRecord" TabIndex="4500">
        <Template>
            <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True">
            </px:PXLayoutRule>
            <px:PXDropDown ID="edOrderType" runat="server" DataField="OrderType">
            </px:PXDropDown>
            <px:PXSelector ID="edOrderNbr" runat="server" DataField="OrderNbr" AutoRefresh="True" CommitChanges="True">
            </px:PXSelector>
            <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True"/>
            <px:PXSelector ID="edLineNbr" runat="server" CommitChanges="True" DataField="LineNbr">
            </px:PXSelector>
        </Template>
    </px:PXFormView>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont3" ContentPlaceHolderID="phG" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100; margin-top: 0px;" 
        Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Details" TabIndex="21000" KeepPosition="True" SyncPosition="True" AdjustPageSize="Manual">
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataKeyNames="OrderType,OrderNbr,LineNbr" DataMember="POReceiptLineRecord">
                <RowTemplate>
                    <px:PXSegmentMask ID="edInventoryID" runat="server" DataField="InventoryID" CommitChanges="True" Size="M" Width="200px">
                    </px:PXSegmentMask>
                    <px:PXNumberEdit ID="edReceiptQty" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="ReceiptQty" CommitChanges="True" Size="S">
                    </px:PXNumberEdit>
                </RowTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ReceiptQty" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                </Columns>
            </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
    </px:PXGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

This is the PEPOOrderReconciliationMaint code:

```
public class PEPOOrderReconciliationMaint : PXGraph<PEPOOrderReconciliationMaint, POLine>
{
    public PXSelect<POLine> POOrderReconcileRecord;

    public PXSelect<POReceiptLine,
                Where<
                    POReceiptLine.pOType, Equal<Current<POLine.orderType>>,
                    And<POReceiptLine.pONbr, Equal<Current<POLine.orderNbr>>,
                    And<POReceiptLine.pOLineNbr, Equal<Current<POLine.lineNbr>>>>>> POReceiptLineRecord;

    #region Cache Attached
    #region OrderType
    [PXDBString(2, IsFixed = true, IsKey = true)]
    [POOrderType.List()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type", Enabled = true)]
    protected virtual void POLine_OrderType_CacheAttached(PXCache Sender)
    {
    }
    #endregion
    #region OrderNbr
    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "", IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Nbr.", Visible = true)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<POOrder.orderNbr,
        Where<POOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<POLine.orderType>>>>))]
    protected virtual void POLine_OrderNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache Sender)
    {
    }
    #endregion
    #region LineNbr
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Line Nbr.", Visible = true, Enabled = true)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<POLine.lineNbr,
            Where<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Current<POLine.orderNbr>>,
            And<POLine.orderType, Equal<Current<POLine.orderType>>>>>))]
    protected virtual void POLine_LineNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache Sender)
    {
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: This type of issues is usually caused by an incorrect Aspx markup. Can you please update your question with Aspx markup of your custom inquiry page?

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question with the Aspx code @RuslanDev

Comment: May I additionally ask you to update your question with the **PEPOOrderReconciliationMaint** source code?

Comment: @RuslanDev I updated the question with the PEPOOrderReconciliationMaint graph code. Thanks

Comment: I updated the question with the PEPOOrderReconciliationMaint graph code. Thanks @RuslanDev